# Paypal Automatic Payment using API

Tags: api, paypal, payment

This is my scenario "Peter have 5€ credit on his account in my website that he recharged with his PayPal account.
Peter can use his virtual credit in the website shop. 
When Peter's balance falls below a certain level(eg. 1€), I want to automatically start a payment with Peter's PayPal account.
In this way his virtual credit can be automatically recharged."
I would like to know if it is possible to put this scenario in place using PayPal API and what API I can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there used to be Reference Transactions, in the classic API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ec-set-up-reference-transactions/ .  Having access to make those API calls requires business approval from PayPal.

In newer REST APIs, nothing similar is publicly documented.  PayPal partners and businesses with some significant commercial history might have access to certain advanced things, but if you have no business history it's probable that the sort of advanced / automatic billing capabilities you're looking for won't be available to you.